# SCSS styling not getting applied to the files

Tags: html, css, saas

[Image Shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mi2fy.png)

My scss styles are not being applied. Please help me figure out the issue. I have attached the github link of the project and also the image of the console.

https://github.com/webdeveloper1213/saasProject

Thanks.

Comment: Do you think you're having an issue with your build process, compiling the sass? Try to narrow down the problem and explain your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting spaces around the `=` signs in your HTML attributes. You shouldn't do that. Remove the extra spaces on both sides of `=`.

The real problem here is that you have a typo of `link ref` for `link rel`. So the browser doesn’t know that you mean to indicate a stylesheet link.

In the future you can catch errors like this by using an HTML validator: https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining me what was going wrong and thanks for the HTML validator link.  That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I just checked your index file update your code
from this

```
<link ref = "stylesheet" href = "/dist/style.css" />
```

to this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./dist/style.css">
```

Comment: I made the changes to index.html and still I don't see the scss styles. I don't understand what I am missing here. Please help.Thanks.